# How to work with field update in workflow?

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update

I have two fields,
A and B
i am using workflow on both field for field update...

criteria is like,
If A = 1 then b should be 1..
both are picklist fields..Like 
A contains HI,none
b contains HI,none

now the Problem is field is updating properly but when i am changing it to NONE,
as e.g, if A=None then its showing B= HI only...its not updating to none...

can you suggest on this? or i need formula for it..?

Comment: Is "None" definitely a valid option in the B picklist values?

Comment: Try using ISCHANGED, or ISNEW on B

Answer (score 0):

[image: WF Criteria]

Please check your evaluation criteria. if it is created and every time it's edited then it should be impacted every time you create and update the record. 
Hope you have rule criteria correct.

Answer (score 0):

What I could suggest is make the field B a non picklist text field, since any changes on this field still brings the value of field A.

Make it a read only text field unless your company has a different requirements with it.

An make sure you have 'treat blank field as blank' or you could just either have the action as

if fieldA__c != NULL, fieldA__c, NULL.

Hope this helps. ^_^